# How to pass a value from <a> (anchor tag) to a function in react js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a CRUD application using react and mvc .net. On clicking the edit/delete link in the table, I want the corresponding EmpID to be passed to a function and then it should be passed to a controller, where edit/delete operation happens. Please let me know how to do this.

```
var EmployeeRow = React.createClass({

    Editnavigate: function(){

    },

    Deletenavigate: function(){

    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.item.EmployeeID}</td>
                <td>{this.props.item.FirstName}</td>
                <td>{this.props.item.LastName}</td>

                <td>
                    <a href="#" data-value="this.props.item.EmployeeID" onclick=this.Editnavigate>edit</a> | 
                    <a href="#" data-value="this.props.item.EmployeeID" onclick=this.Deletenavigate>delete</a>
                </td>               
            </tr>

        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using `onClick`, as simple as this

```
Editnavigate (e,id) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(id);
}

<a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.Editnavigate(e,1)}>edit</a> // pass your id inplace of 1
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a-click-passdata)**

> Note : You can also pass via `data-value` , but still that's not good
>   idea, in that case you still need to access dom and fetch via that
>   field, instead that just pass the value when its possible. That will
>   be simple and requires less processing.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the data you want from your click handlers like this:

```
EditNavigable: function(e) {
    var clickedLink = e.currentTarget;
    var data = clickedLink.getAttribute('data-value');
}
```

Or you could put it into it's own function like so:

```
getDataValue: function(e) {
    return e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-value');
}
```

and then call it from your edit and delete functions like this:

```
EditNavigable: function(e) {
    var data = this.getDataValue(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below. I was trying the same in reactjs with javascript(ES-6), but nothing else worked except for below-

```
<a href = 'www.google.com' onClick={clickHandler} > Google </a>

clickHandler(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("This is alert: " + event.target.getAttribute('href'));
}

Here event.target.getAttribute('href') will return 'www.google.com'
```